# How to curry function with two parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying

I have a function `buckets` with type `Integral a => [a] -> Int -> Int -> [[a]]` and I want use it in `foldl` in this way:

```
basketsort lst = foldl (f) lst [1..3]
f lst = reverse . concat . (flip buckets 9) lst
```

The function `f` works, and has a type `Integral a => [a] -> Int -> [a]`, but if I reduce `lst` parameter, compilation fails.

Is it possible to reduce more than one parameter by currying and use `f`'s body in foldl without declaration of `f`? Something like this:

```
basketsort lst = foldl (reverse . concat . (flip buckets 9)) lst [1..3]
```

Comment: [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io) suggests `f = ((reverse . join) .) . flip buckets 9`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann this works, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand the second application of the dot operator:

```
    f lst = reverse . concat . (flip buckets 9) lst
==> f lst = (.) (reverse . concat) ((flip buckets 9) lst)
```

then the eta-reduction becomes obvious:

```
    f = (.) (reverse . concat) . (flip buckets 9)
```

But come on, do you really want to do that? Not a very nice present for whoever is going to maintain your code after you're gone.

Answer (score 2):

First: I recommend not to use `flip` just to apply a function partially to its second argument; this can be done better with an infix section. (Or, perhaps the arguments of `bucket` should be the other way around in the first place?)

So, you want to make

```
f lst = reverse . concat . (`buckets`9) lst
```

pointfree. The problem is that you need to pass two arguments to the rightmost element in the composition chain. One way to do this is to use *uncurried* form (because then those two arguments come in just a single value):

```
f = curry $ reverse . concat . uncurry (`buckets`9)
```

An alternative is to use specialised combinators. The [`pointless-fun` package has this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-fun-1.1.0.6/docs/Data-Function-Pointless.html#v:.:):

```
f = reverse . concat .: (`buckets`9)
```

A more standard, though IMO rather ugly alternative is to use the function-functor: you can map over a function, which corresponds to composing after it:

```
f = fmap (reverse . concat) . (`buckets`9)
```

The best alternative frankly is to keep that parameter named:

```
basketsort lst = foldl (\l -> reverse . concat . buckets l 9) lst [1..3]
```